# MediaWiki import failing: Fatal exception of type "DBUnexpectedError"

Tags: mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki instance set up on a Heroku server with a Postgres database. I'm trying to import the Template: Infobox Fictional Location (and all the dependencies) from Wikipedia. I used Special:Export and Special:Import, but I'm getting "Fatal exception of type 'DBUnexpectedError'". When importing pages without templates, all goes well. Only when I include or try to explicitly export templates does it go poorly. I have Scribunto installed, and I *think* properly configured?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, on shared hosting, you probably don't know what kind of OS your server is on. To get around this, open up your ssh and from ''/path/to/extensions/Scribunto/engines/LuaStandalone/binaries/'' run

```bash
$ chmod a+x l*/lua
```

That way, you'll change the lua file in all of the directories.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue when I forgot to run:
chmod a+x /path/to/extensions/Scribunto/engines/LuaStandalone/binaries/yourOS/lua

Try that.